# How do I add a non-breaking whitespace in JavaScript without using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, whitespace, innerhtml, createelement, createtextnode

I'm generating content dynamically and in some instances, I need to set a `&nbsp;` as the only content of a `<span>` element.

However, the following adds `&nbsp;` as text vs adding a empty space:

```
var foo = document.createElement("span")
foo = document.createTextNode("&nbsp;");
```

which makes sense, so I'm wondering, how would I add `&nbsp;` correctly without (!) using `innerHTML`

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why would you **not** want to use `innerHTML`?

Comment: Try: document.createTextNode("\u00a0");

Comment: @David: because I was looking for a way to run this through an existing method without having to add an extra clause to use `innerHTML` in case I need to add a whitespace.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can use a unicode literal for a [non breaking space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm):

```
var foo = document.createTextNode("\u00A0");
```

Comment: text = text.replace(/\s/g, '\u00A0');    - replaces all spaces with their unicode literal

Comment: This is perfect.  It also works in the JQuery `text()` command: `link.text("(hide\u00A0info)");`

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to use `innerHTML`, you can use a hexadecimal escape.

The most common:

- `\x20` – standard space or `\s`
- `\xC2\xA0` – non-breaking space or `&nbsp;`
- `\x0D` – carriage return or `\r`
- `\x0A` – newline or `\n`
- `\x09` – tab or `\t`

In your case: `\xC2\xA0`

Comment: Check out this site for more Information[link] http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=128&number=128&utf8=string-literal&unicodeinhtml=hex

Answer (score 5):

Append the non breaking space to your parent node, let us refer to it as "parent" below i.e.:

`parent.append("\u00A0");`

source: `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append`

Comment: I see you are new to the platform. You should not answer a question unless you have something that was not covered by the existing answers.

Comment: I believe that the use of .innerHTML is a bad choice for a adding a simple &nbsp; as it is very slow and also may add to security risk; thus my answer should be seen in that context.

Comment: So, make your point in the answer :) explain why innerHTML is a bad choice, add references, you can create code snippets and you may show that it is slow.

And welcome to the comunity