# Align Guitar Chords on Web

Tags: javascript, html, css, seo

I am trying to figure out a good way to display guitar chords on the web in a variable-width font, preferably using just HTML and CSS if possible. I'm trying to do this by lining up the chord above a specific letter.

I've come up with the following solution ( 
https://jsfiddle.net/u33v87ob/ ):

HTML:

```
<div class="chunk">
  <span class="chord"></span>
  <br>
  <span class="lyric">As&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class="chunk">
  <span class="chord">C</span>
  <br>
  <span class="lyric">I was going over the&nbsp;</span>
</div>
<div class="chunk">
  <span class="chord">Am</span>
  <br>
  <span class="lyric">far fam'd Kerry Mountains,</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.chunk {
  float: left;
}
```

From a display perspective this works perfectly. However, search engines read it like this, which means that I lose out on search results for the lyrics:

```
As CI was going over theAmfar fam'd Kerry Mountains
```

Trying to copy+paste results in garbled output as well. I would rather copied text look like:

```
CAm
As I was going over the far fam'd Kerry Mountains,
```

Is there some way I can accomplish this?

**Edit:** For posterity, [here is an extension on the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50359172/998251) which you should definitely check out if this answer is helpful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not simply relying on pseudo element and data attribute:

```css
p {
 margin-top:50px;
}
span.chunk {
 position:relative;
}
span.chunk:before {
  content:attr(data-chord);
  position:absolute;
  top:-15px;
}
```

```html
<p>
As
<span class="chunk" data-chord="C">I was going over the</span> 
<span class="chunk" data-chord="Am">far fam'd Kerry Mountains,</span></p>
```

Comment: Cool @Temani Afif, do you know a way to avoid overlapping chords when they are very close together?

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

I found a way of doing the same thing as [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) but also making sure that the chords do not overlap. When they are too close together, we move them to the right the required distance for them not to go over each other.

See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1hvs285p/5/).

### HTML

```html
<p>
  As <span class="chunk" data-chord="C"></span>I was going over 
  <span class="chunk" data-chord="Am"></span>th<span class="chunk" data-chord="E"></span>e
</p>
<p>
  <span class="chunk" data-chord="Am"></span>
  <span class="chunk" data-chord="C"></span>far fam'd Kerry 
  <span class="chunk" data-chord="C7"></span>Mountains
</p>
```

### JavaScript

```js
// Function to get the width of the chord text
function getTextWidth(text, font) {
  // if given, use cached canvas for better performance
  // else, create new canvas
  var canvas = getTextWidth.canvas || (getTextWidth.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"));
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.font = font;
  var metrics = context.measureText(text);
  return metrics.width;
};

// Function to obtain a CSS property of an element
function getCSS(element, property) {
  return window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(property);
}

// Function to check if two chord spans overlap
function chordsOverlap(el1, el2) {
  const domElement1 = el1.getBoundingClientRect();
  const domElement1Text = getTextWidth(el1.getAttribute('data-chord'), getCSS(el1, 'font'));
  const domElement2 = el2.getBoundingClientRect();
  const domElement2Text = getTextWidth(el2.getAttribute('data-chord'), getCSS(el2, 'font'));

  return !(
    domElement1.top > domElement2.bottom ||
    domElement1.left + domElement1Text < domElement2.left ||
    domElement1.bottom < domElement2.top ||
    domElement1.left > domElement2.left + domElement2Text
  );
}

// Function to get the x-offset between two chords that do overlap
function xOffset(el1, el2) {
  const domElement1 = el1.getBoundingClientRect();
  const domElement1Text = getTextWidth(el1.getAttribute('data-chord'), getCSS(el1, 'font'));
  const domElement2 = el2.getBoundingClientRect();
  const domElement2Text = getTextWidth(el2.getAttribute('data-chord'), getCSS(el2, 'font'));

  return domElement1.left + domElement1Text - domElement2.left;
}


// Function to callibrate the chords so that they do not overlap
function callibrateChords() {
  const chords = document.querySelectorAll('span.chunk');
  const spaceWidth = getTextWidth('\u00A0', getCSS(chords[0], 'font'));
  for (let i = 0; i < chords.length - 1; i++) {
    let ch1 = chords[i];
    let ch2 = chords[i + 1];
    if (chordsOverlap(ch1, ch2)) {
      //console.log(i, i+1, true, xOffset(ch1, ch2))
      let chordContent = ch2.getAttribute('data-chord').replace(/\u00A0/g, '');
      ch2.setAttribute('data-chord', '\u00A0'.repeat(Math.round(xOffset(ch1, ch2) / spaceWidth) + 1) + chordContent)
    } else {
      //console.log(i, i+1, false)
    }
  }
}

callibrateChords();
```

### CSS

```css
p {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

span.chunk {
  position: relative;
}

span.chunk:before {
  content: attr(data-chord);
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  color: red;
}
```

## References

- Getting the font from an element: [How to get the actual rendered font when it's not defined in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7444724/15159198)
- Adding non-breaking spaces [How do I add a non-breaking whitespace in JavaScript without using innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19810238/15159198)
- Getting rendered text width: [Calculate text width with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21015393/15159198)
- Checking if two elements overlap: [Check if two Elements overlap using JavaScript](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-check-if-two-elements-overlap)